# Validating data Id's between Microservices

Tags: c#, rest, microservices

I have two services that are separate REST Api's:

- Users (api/Users)
- Cooks (api/Cooks)

There is also a Gateway API that will route requests between services.

The entities are related as follows:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    //Other properties relating to a user
}

public class Cook
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}

    //Other properties relating to a cook
}
```

I can POST to api/Users and create a new user. A user can then become a cook at some point if they choose to. Meaning I would POST to api/Cooks and have to specify the 'UserId' to associate it with.

I now need to:

1. Validate that the UserId is valid (i.e. exists)
2. If the UserId is valid then it should not already be associated with a Cook (i.e. one-to-one)

So, my question is. How should this validation be performed and where should it happen in this approach? How can the Cook service know that it has received a valid UserId?

Comment: Ask users service about that?

Comment: What is a valid user id for you?

Comment: @Evk That is possible. Does it violate anything by coupling myself to the other service? i.e. I would make a HTTP request to the Users service to request the info? Or is it just about failing gracefully is the other service was down for any reason?

Comment: @Isma A valid UserId is one that exists in the Users service and is not already associated to a Cook.

Comment: Well you either have shared state (database for example, which is used by all\several services) or you ask service which "owns" information, there is no other way. Sometimes, you can also synchronize state of multiple services (so both have "database" with users and cooks service periodically pulls updates from users service with new\changed\deleted users).

Comment: I think you should start by asking yourself if the Cookservice really is responsible for checking if the user exists, as you create a dependency between both services what forfeits the purpose of independent microservices. And if you check if the user exists, shouldn't you also check if the user sending the request has the right to set the user to be a cook? You might be able to represent your data in a shared JWT token as a shared state like Evk suggests, so you can be sure the sending user really sends a valid userid as the UserService signed the JWT-Token.

Comment: So you would have to make a query to validate that condition, either before sending the data (design by contract) so the second service assumes the data is always correct or you do the query to validate in the second service (deffensive programming) and return an error if it is not correct. I would go for the second option or even both.

Comment: That said, you should ensure that using shared database is not an option for you (nothing prevents from doing this even with microservices: http://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html) and ensure that you are not doing all this just because it's fancy.

Answer (score 0):

One service calling another service is totally fine.

When you receive a request to your Gateway API you should send same request to your Cooks service and Cooks service validates the user id against Users service.

Hope this helps